# How to get Rad Tree nodes not getting aligned

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I've a radtree with nodes in it in which some of the nodes have an image along with the text. Now, when they're rendered, the nodes get aligned from the start of the content. I want the text part of the nodes to be aligned. Please find the attached image for more clarification.

I tried adding a css class and a content css class. But I think the properties I mentioned are overridden.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Noel

[image: browse tree]

Comment: THey're essentially telerik controls. asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from Telerik support:

You can use the following css class selector to position the image before the text and keep its current position:

```
<style> 
div.RadTreeView .rtImg 
{
margin-left: -16px; 
} 
</style>
```